# How to give custom width to UIContextualAction in TableView (swipe)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a simple TableView :

[image]

Currently, this what I have when I swipe on left by using a UIContextualAction :

[image]

My current code :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
{
    let editAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Modifier", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        print("OK, marked as Closed")
        success(true)
    })
    editAction.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "leftView")
    //editAction.backgroundColor = .black

    let configuration =  UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [editAction])
    //configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
    return configuration
}
```

And this is what I want :

[image]

Like you can see there, the swiped button is going until the middle of the cell. How Can I do that please ?

Comment: You cannot specify the size of the UIContextualAction buttons the system decides on it based on the text and/or images being used.  If you really wanted to do something like that you have to abandon the built in functionality and go for a full manual situation using swipe gestures, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems in iOS11 either image of a specific size or text only will be accepted for tableviewcell swipe.

Another option is to add gesture to tableview.

Or adding pan gesture to tableviewcell like, initially create a view in the custom cell and use UIPanGestureRecognizer to this view in the cell. Add the buttons needed to the custom cell, when you swipe the view in the custom cell, the buttons in the custom cell shall be visible.

Comment: It doesn't seems to fit great with what I need